# How to Get relationship from notification bi Id in Laravel

Tags: database, laravel, notifications

I'm Trying view Database Notification in Laravel 5.6

my class
`class LeavesNotification extends Notification
{

```
use Queueable;

/**
 * Create a new notification instance.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public $data;

public function __construct($data)
{
    $this->data= $data;
}


/**
 * Get the notification's delivery channels.
 *
 * @param  mixed  $notifiable
 * @return array
 */
public function via($notifiable)
{
    //return ['mail'];
    return ['database'];
}



/**
 * Get the mail representation of the notification.
 *
 * @param  mixed  $notifiable
 * @return \Illuminate\Notifications\Messages\MailMessage
 */
public function toMail($notifiable)
{
    return (new MailMessage)
                ->line('The introduction to the notification.')
                ->action('Notification Action', url('/'))
                ->line('Thank you for using our application!');
}

/**
 * Get the array representation of the notification.
 *
 * @param  mixed  $notifiable
 * @return array
 */
public function toArray($notifiable)
{
    
    return $this->data->toArray();
}
```

}`

My controller :

[image]

My table employees in database :
[image]

My table leaves :
[image]

Comment: what is your question?

Comment: [I downvoted because an image of your controller code isn't helpful](http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode).